# How to get user from lat/long and radius in mongodb using php?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in which there are multiple users having there lat,long,radius(to capture user within the radius.)

e.g. 
If A user has below detail:

```
    lat" : 28.545350,
    long" : 77.401638,
    service_distance : "7.0",
```

based on lat/long & radius I have to find user within 7.0Km radius.

DB COLLECTION E.G

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("563f8892cb0d26665f884791"),
    "user_id" : "563f8090cb0d26e95e884791",
    "lat" : "28.545350",
    "long" : "77.401638",
    "service_distance" : "7.0",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-11-10T16:31:06.382Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-11-08T17:38:26.863Z")
```

Comment: You should take a look at MongoDB [geospatial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/) and [queries](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/). The core thing to learn is that if you restructure your data to suit the storage and index requirements, then this is very easy. Particularly storing as [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/), where all distances are reported and used in metric quantities. Also note in your reading of those sources **"Do not use strings for numeric values"**

Comment: @blakes seven , thanks I need to restructure data.

Comment: Follow the docs. The basic point is `lat` and `long` cannot be separate fields, but need to be in a supported format. Also the index features both make `$near` or `$nearSphere` operations possible, as well as adding performance improvements to other geospatial operations.

Comment: I think you should have a look at this [SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908549/filter-documents-by-distance-stored-in-document-with-near), answered by @BlakesSeven BTW

Comment: @Pynchia I also belive that is the ultimate goal of the question. The main points I think now that need to be absorbed by the OP are the data structure and geospatial index concepts as already pointed to. But considering the overall question, I think your input is also of value here.